# Constructing an NFA for a language defined over $\Sigma = \{0, 1\}$

Tags: automata, finite-automata, nondeterminism

The language is defined as $$L = \{0^n10^m10^q \mid n,m,q \in \mathbb{N}, q \equiv nm \mod 5\}.$$ Can someone help me get started on this question? I don't know what part of the question I should do first. I have made an automaton that keeps track of $\mod 5$, what next?

Answer (score 0):

Use nondeterminism to guess the remainder of $nm \div 5$ and then check that this is also the remainder of $q \div 5$.

Comment: Well this is kind of obvious, I am just not sure how to use nondeterminism. So far, I have found out n mod 5. Suppose n mod 5 = 1, now what am i supposed to do? find out the number of ms?

Comment: Use epsilon-transitions to guess what the remainder of $nm$ should be.

Comment: yeah this doesnt seem right, I am going to start over.

Comment: What exactly do u mean by epsilon transitions?

Comment: Epsilon-transitions (sometimes called lambda-transitions) are transitions are labelled with the empty string. They allow the NFA to change state without reading an input symbol.